# jquery function requires 1 extra click to work

Tags: jquery

So, the first problem is .select has to be clicked 2 times to execute the timer. After selecting a task, .select gets the text: "Start task!", which changes on click, and the function clock is supposed to start after .select which has the text of "Start task!" and the same with the pause task. Tho it has to be clicked 2 times. The second problem is when i tried to pause timer by giving it fixed vars of taskMins1 and taskSeks1, it only sped up the countdown process.

```
$(".select").click(function () {
       $(this).text(function(i, text){
       return text === "Start task!" ? "Pause task!" : "Start task!";
       })  
    });
    var taskMins1 = $(this).siblings('.task-time').children('.minutes').text();
            var taskSeks1 = $(this).siblings('.task-time').children('.seconds').text();
            $('.select').click(function(){
                if($('.select').text() == 'Start task!'){
                $('.select').click(function clock(){
                    $('.task-time-left').html(taskMins1 + ":" + taskSeks1)
                    taskSeks1--;
                    if(taskSeks1 <10 && taskSeks1 >= 0){taskSeks1="0" + taskSeks1}
                    if(taskSeks1 < 0){taskSeks1 = 59, taskMins1 = taskMins1 - 1}
                    $('.task-time-left').html(taskMins1 + ":" + taskSeks1)
                    setTimeout(clock, 1000)
                });
                }
                else{
                    $('.task-time-left').html(taskMins1 + ":" + taskSeks1)
                }
            })
```

Comment: You are setting the `.select` click handler twice in the same block, without being nested. I doubt that it is what you are looking for

Comment: @Isac my function doesnt work at all without the outer click event handler, and i dont know how to replace that

Comment: can't you just move whatever inside the second click into the 1st click?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems in your code. Firstly you are setting the `click` handler for `.select` twice in your code:

```
$(".select").click(function() {
  ...
});
var taskMins1 = $(this).siblings('.task-time').children('.minutes').text();
var taskSeks1 = $(this).siblings('.task-time').children('.seconds').text();
$('.select').click(function() {
  ...
```

Which is not what you want, you want to define one click handler and combine both codes. Basically take the code in your first `click handler`

```
$(this).text(function(i, text){
   return text === "Start task!" ? "Pause task!" : "Start task!";
});
```

Into the second one.

Secondly you are missing semi colons all over the place. And lastly the `setTimeout` has to be defined in a separate function from the one in the click handler or stored in a variable.

Regardless what you are looking for is [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) which allows you to keep executing indefinitely and stop with [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Making all those changes in your code it would look like this:

```js
//simplified the fetching of the html elements to keep the html simple
var taskMins1 = $('.minutes').text(); 
var taskSeks1 = $('.seconds').text();

let timer; //variable to keep the timer and allow stopping the clock

$('.select').click(function() { //only one click handler
  if ($('.select').text() == 'Start task!') {

      timer = setInterval(function(){

        if (--taskSeks1 < 0) {
          if (--taskMins1 >= 0) taskSeks1 = 59;
          
          if (taskMins1 <0){ //if minutes and seconds are zero stop the timer
              taskMins1 = 0;
              taskSeks1 = 0;
              clearInterval(timer);
          }
        }
        $('.task-time-left').html(taskMins1 + ":" + (taskSeks1 < 10 ? "0" + taskSeks1 : taskSeks1) );
      },1000);
     
  } else {
    $('.task-time-left').html(taskMins1 + ":" + (taskSeks1 < 10 ? "0" + taskSeks1 : taskSeks1) );
    clearInterval(timer); //clears the timer to stop the task
  }
  
  //the previous first click handler is now here
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    return text === "Start task!" ? "Pause task!" : "Start task!";
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="select">Select</button>
<div class="task-time">
  <div class="minutes">1</div>
  <div class="seconds">12</div>
</div>


<div class="task-time-left"></div>
```

Comment: The only bug I see in your code is inconsistent padding of seconds with 0 in your time. For example, when running I would see 1:07, but when stopped it becomes 1:7. Nonetheless, I am  impressed with your ability to clean up the OP's code.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy Indeed, i hadn't even noticed it because it only happens when you stop at a second below 10, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set text = 'Start task!' on the first click, then your condition on the second click will evaluate to true:

```
text === "Start task!"
```

It's a problem of initializing that text value on page load to accomplish what you want. I assume you'd want to make sure the text is initially "Start Task!".

Comment: The problem is that when i click button, lets call it "task select", it updates text to "start task!' after which I was hoping the function would go normally, but i have to click it again so the text displays "start task" which is the exact opposite of what i wanted